# Как использовать сырой SQL в функции контроллера Laravel 5.5

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Делаю проект и очень ограничен во времени, сидеть и изучать перевод SQL в Eloquent сейчас просто некогда, тем более, что SQL запрос не тривиальный:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_movies
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(
    movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM user_movies WHERE user_id = 305344)
    ) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Но дело даже не в самом запросе, вопрос проще:
   Как использовать SQL запросы в таком виде как есть, но в контроллере Laravel?

Если интересно, то запрос делает следующее: ищет в общей таблице все записи (в каждой записи есть id пользователя и id фильма многократно встречающиеся в таблице), группирует их по id пользователя, затем сортирует по убыванию количества идентичных фильмов по сравнению с текущим пользователем, id которого - 305344. Чтобы перевести это в Eloquent у меня неделя уйдёт.

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(логическое выражение)` - это на грани гениальности... не проще было взять сразу 2 копии таблицы, связанные по равенству movie_id и **НЕ**равенству user_id? А ещё - формально идея запроса неявно предполагает, что юзер, id которого = 305344, будет в выдаче первым, но если есть юзер, у которого есть ВСЕ фильмы, которые есть у заданного юзера, то неизвестно, кто будет первым в итоговом наборе...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий и разбор, я конечно учту это на будущее. Но сейчас мне нужно решить конкретную проблему - запуск сырого SQL. Кстати, первым выходит текущий юзер, даже если у другого такой же набор фильмов, но не факт, что при каких-то других обстоятельствах это не измениться.

Comment: Надеюсь найти ответ тут: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/database

Comment: *Надеюсь найти ответ тут* Да есть он там. Причём в открытом виде... *не факт, что при каких-то других обстоятельствах это не измениться* Имеет полное право. Поставьте в выражении сортировки `ORDER BY user_id = 305344 DESC, остальные выражения` (для MySQL, или аналогично через CASE для других диалектов) - тогда можно гарантировать требуемый порядок. Вот только параметр придётся передавать дважды - в условие отбора и в условие сортировки, но это вряд ли проблема.

Comment: Сортировку применил, только поставил ASC, тогда этот пользователь вообще не входит в результаты, а это то, что мне и нужно в идеале.

Comment: А не проще тупо во WHERE добавить `AND user_id != 305344`? он ещё до сортировки не войдёт в набор...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73475/discussion-between---and-akina).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно поможет метод сырых выражений DB::raw()
[Ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions)